# JConsole heap dump much smaller than memory usage

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot

We have a few containers running java processes with docker. One thing we've been noticing is a huge amount of memory that is taken up just by running a simple spring-boot app without even including our own code (just to try and get some kind of memory profile independent of any issues we might introduce).

What I saw was the memory consumed by docker/the JVM was hovering around 2.5. We did have a decent amount of extra deps included in it (camel, hibernate, some spring-boot deps) but that wasn't what really threw me off. What I saw was that despite docker saying it consumed 2.5GB of memory for the app, running jconsole against it read that it was consuming up to 1GB (down to ~200MB after a GC and slowly climbing). The memory footprint on docker remained where it was after the GC as well (2.5GB).

Furthermore, when I dumped the heap to see what kinds of object are taking up that space, it looks like the heap was only 33MB large after I loaded the .hprof file into MAT. None of this makes much sense to me. Currently, I'm looking at the non-heap space in jconsole reported at 115MB while the heap space is at 331MB.

I've already read a ton (on SO and other sites) about the JVM memory regions and some things specifically reporting that the heap dumps might be smaller but none of them were this far off that I could tell and beyond that, many of the suggested things to watch for were that the GC is run whenever a heap dump is taken and that MAT has a setting to show or hide unreachable objects. All of this was taken into account before posting here and now I just feel like something else is at play that I can't capture myself and I haven't found online.

I fully expect that the numbers might be a little off but it seems extreme that they're off by a factor of 10 in the best case scenario and off by nearly a factor of 100 when looking at the docker-reported memory usage.

Does anyone know what I might be missing here?

EDIT: This is also an app running with Java 8, not yet running with Java 11. It's on the JIRA board to do but not yet planned for.

EDIT2: Adding screenshots. Spike in the JConsole screen shot is from running GC.

[image: Docker Stats with memory usage]

[image: JConsole heap memory usage]

[image: MAT heap dump]

Comment: It would help probably if you could post some of the actual output (e.g. a jconsole screenshot)

Comment: Done. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: `and off by nearly a factor of 100 when looking at the docker-reported memory usage.` - could be that docker reports the whole memory taken by the image not just by you java app?

Comment: I thought that but actually reading the memory from the process inside the docker container revealed that, yes, it is almost entirely the java app. For reference, this is an alpine docker container which is rather lightweight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JConsole gives you the amount of committed memory: 3311616 KiB ~= 3GiB
This is how much memory your java process consumes, as seen by the OS.

It is unrelated to how much heap is currently in use to hold Java objects, also reported by JConsole as 130237 kbyte ~= 130 MiB.

This is also unrelated to how many Objects are actually alive: By default MAT will remove unreachable Objects when you load the heap dump. You can enable the option by going to Preferences -> Memory Analyzer -> Keep Unreachable Objects (See [the MAT documentation](https://wiki.eclipse.org/MemoryAnalyzer/FAQ)). So if you have a lot of short lived objects, the difference can be quite massive.

I see that it also reports a Max Heap of about 9GiB. It means that you have set Xmx parameter to a large value.

Hotspot GC's are not very good at reclaiming unused memory. They tend to use all the space available to them (the Max heap size, set by Xmx) and then never decommit the heap, effectively keeping it reserved for the Java process instead of releasing it to the OS.

If you want to minimize the memory footprint of your process from the OS perspective, I recommend that you set a lower Xmx, maybe -Xmx1g, so as to not allow Java to grow too much (of course, Xmx will also need to be high enough to accomodate for your application workload!).

If really want an adaptative heap, you can also switch to G1 (-XX:+UseG1GC) and a more recent Java, as the hotspot team has delivered [some improvements](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/346) recently.

Comment: I would be surprised if this isn't where the issue lies. Just to guess, would the option "-XX:-UseContainerSupport" be useful here with the larger Xmx param? I'm just curious because while I want to provide enough heap space should the process require it, I do want it releasing that memory.

Comment: I was not aware of UseContainerSupport. It is a recently introduced option (Java 10), so you won't have it in Java 8. If my understanding of https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8146115 is correct, the fact that it is not there is why your JVM defaulted to such a large Xmx. Also, in any case, UseContainerSupport is not going to help you in any way with heap shrinking. Only an upgrade to java 12 will!

Comment: Apparently it's been backported to 8u191 as well. https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u191-relnotes-5032181.html. Thanks for all the help regardless if this option helps. I feel like it just comes down to option tweaking at this point. That's something though. I think we can manage with that.

Answer (score 0):

Dave

OS monitoring tools will show to you the amount of memory that is allocated by a process. So this:
 [image]
mean that your java process have 2.664G of memory allocated (java heap + meta space)

JConsole shows to you the memory that your code is "consuming" (ignoring the meta space)

I see 2 possible explanations:

1. You have set -Xms with a huge value
2. You have a lot of static
       code (or other content) loaded on your meta space.